# Read/write a CuPy array on multiple GPUs

Tags: pointers, ctypes, multi-gpu, cupy

I have a large array. I need to process parts of this array on multiple GPUs to not copy the same array to every GPU. I have four GPUs and I create a CuPy array on device 0 and I was able to obtain the array pointer too. But I don't know a method to dereference this pointer on the other devices. My example code is:

```
import cupy as cp

with cp.cuda.Device(0):
    x     = cp.zeros((4, 4), dtype=cp.int32)
    x_ptr = x.data.ptr     # CuPy array pointer
with cp.cuda.Device(1):
    print(x)               # prints the array with no error
    x[0, 0] = 99           # Error: Array device must be same as the current device: array device = 0 while current = 1
```

It's obvious that writing from GPU 1 to GPU 0 is not straightforward and requires pointer dereferencing which I'm not sure how to implement using CuPy.

I tried ctypes to cast the CuPy array to ctypes since there's a known way to dereference pointers using the following code, but I keep getting segfault coredump so I couldn't make further progress:

```
import ctypes
import cupy as cp

with cp.cuda.Device(0):
    x        = cp.zeros((4, 4), dtype=cp.int32)
    x_ctypes = ctypes.cast(x.data.ptr, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int32*x.size))

with cp.cuda.Device(1):
    print(x_ctypes)              # get: <__main__.LP_c_int_Array_16 object at 0x7f29d2841050>
    print(x_ctypes.contents)     # get: <__main__.c_int_Array_16 object at 0x7f29d28410e0>
    print(x_ctypes.contents[0])  # get: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Is there an efficient way to do that without copying array x to GPU 1?
Note: the GPUs have Access Peer enabled

Comment: Currently CuPy only supports peer access when copying an array between GPU devices (`cupy.copyto` etc.). I've filed an issue: https://github.com/cupy/cupy/issues/5379

Comment: Thanks fr your reply and for the filed Github issue. Is there a workaround using ctypes?
Why do I get core dumped?

Comment: No workarounds for now, unfortunately... we will try to get the fix into the release next month. You are getting segfault because you are trying to dereference a GPU memory address as a CPU memory address.

Comment: FYI, here is the line where consistency between the current device and the array device is checked: https://github.com/cupy/cupy/blob/v10.0.0a1/cupy/_core/_kernel.pyx#L76-L97

Comment: Thanks again for being generous. while waiting for this fix to happen, do you mind telling me how I can dereference a GPU memory address properly?

Comment: Perhaps you could use CuPy with Dask? https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/gpu.html#arrays

Comment: I’ll try this too, thanks